# OpenCL context scope for class member?

Tags: c++, opencl

I am reading a book on OpenCL which says

> Unlike functions that create platforms and devices,
>   clCreateContextFromType and clCreateContext return cl_contexts instead
>   of error codes. This means you don’t have to allocate and deallocate
>   memory for the structure. If the cl_context is declared as a local
>   variable, its memory will be automatically freed when the enclosing
>   function terminates.

I am keeping the context as a class member.

```
class MyOpenCL
{
    private:
        cl_context context;
};
```

So will it remain in memory until the class is destructed?
If no then what is an alternative to this?
I do not like the reference counting mechanism.

Comment: If you are using C++ in the first place then use "cl.hpp" instead of plain cl.h methods. They will get deallocated as any other C++ class. You will not need to care about these issues.

Comment: I tried to use cl.hpp, but it seems that it does not work with my environment. MinGW 32 bit compiler on Win7 64 bit OS using AMD APP SDK. The problem was some Visual C++ header files.

Comment: @Cool_Coder Check out Boost.Compute (https://github.com/kylelutz/compute). It provides (IMHO) a much nicer C++ API for OpenCL (as well as many higher-level features) and only depends on the OpenCL C interface (i.e. `cl.h`). For this use-case the Boost.Compute `context` object can be stored as a class member and its memory will automatically be handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if your `cl_context` variable is a class member then the memory used to hold this variable will be retained for the lifetime of your class instance. In fact, a `cl_context` is actually just a pointer to the actual context object, and so the context itself will not be destroyed until you call `clReleaseContext()`, regardless of when the memory holding the `cl_context` variable is deallocated. You should make sure you call `clReleaseContext()` when you are done with the context, for example in the class destructor or some other suitable place.